# How to clean history from Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console

I am looking to clean my Google Search Console dashboard history.
I need to delete all the old results so my console start showing new results just like a fresh Google Search Console dashboard. Is there anyway to do it completely?

I already tried removal tool and refresh out dated content but still console having old record.